# Laravel 5 withError() vs withErrors()

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I could be doing something very stupid. Accidentally produced a piece of code which I cannot seem to figure out how it works.

I am trying to customize unauthenticated user redirection to login page. So when  user tries to access a page that is protected, laravel redirects the user to the login page. I am trying to show a Javascript toastr message in such cases.

What i did was customize the `unauthenticated` method in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` class as follows:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }
    //dd($request);
    return redirect()->guest('login')->withError('You are not logged in or Your session has expired');
}
```

Note that i missed the `s` in the `withError` function. In my blade file i am showing the toastr notification as follows:

```
<script>
 @if(Session::has('error'))

       toastr.error("{{Session::get('error')}}");
 @endif
 </script>
```

So whenever a user is being redirected to the login page because he is not logged in yet, a Java Script toastr message is shown. However, i cannot figure out how the `Session('error')` value is being populated by the `withError` function. I could only find that Laravel has `withErrors` function, not `withError`.

Tried to troubleshoot for last couple hours without luck. Seeking some guidance here. Thanks. Btw, i am very new to Laravel.

Comment: Could you accept my answer if it solved your query please?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It’s a “magic” method, in that any call to a method with a prefix of `with` will be added to the session as flash data. So `withError()` will add flash data under the key `error`; `withErrors()` will add flash data under the key `errors`; `withSuccess()` will add flash data under the key of `success`; and so on.

Comment: It really is!! Thanks a lot. I can go to sleep with peace of mind finally.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Sorry moved out of laravel to Yii for some time so din't check stackoverflow for long !!